# python setting columns as value

Tags: python, python-2.4

I have a txt file with roughly 1000 lines, i want to setup colum 1 as the soruce destination and column 2 as the transfer to destination and using `shutil.copyfile(src, dst)` copy these files.

I have it setup as a simple print (src, dst) right now so i can see whats going on. I'm not doing something right in the `for src in vld` to add in the linux value.

Am i way off with this current setup to get the value of src lined up with the corresponding value of dst ?  I'm using Python 2.4

```
import csv
import operator
import sys
import os
import shutil

inf = csv.reader(open('data.txt','r'))
sortedlist = sorted(inf, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)
def dothis(x):
        for row in sortedlist:
                print row[x]

vld = dothis(0)
linux = dothis(1)

for src in vld:
        dst = linux
        print (src, dst)
```

current error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 16, in ? for src in vld:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

Comment: current error message:  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 16, in ?
    for src in vld:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, but veered off-track somewhere there.  :)  `dothis` doesn't return anything, so `vld` and `linux` are both going to be empty.

`csv.reader` already "lines up" the values for you; it yields rows at a time.  You're actually breaking them apart again when there's no need.

```
inf = csv.reader(open('data.txt','r'))
sortedlist = sorted(inf, key=operator.itemgetter(2), reverse=True)

for row in sortedlist:
    src = row[0]
    dst = row[1]
    print src, dst
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in ?
    for src, dst in sortedlist:
ValueError: too many values to unpack`
How are the values src and dst defined doing it this way? the dothis function allows me to show a row i specify in my case 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: ah, are there more than two columns in your file?  the way i had it assumes there's just a source column and a destination column, and they become `src, dst` in that order.  i'll edit

Comment: i understand now, vld was only working off the 1 row i had given it so it was unable to add the two properly.   Thanks!